# How to create a representable hex int by string concatenation?

Tags: python-3.x, unicode

Consider:

```
>>> a = '\xe3'
>>> a
'ã'
>>> a.encode('cp1252')
b'\xe3'
```

I would like to recreate the `a` variable if the user input the string `e3`:

```
>>> from_user = 'e3'
>>> a = '\x' + from_user
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: end of string in escape sequence
>>> a = '\\x' + from_user
>>> a
'\\xe3'
>>> a.encode('cp1252')
b'\\xe3'
```

With the string `from_user`, how might I create the `a` variable such that I could use it just like I did in the first example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you an idea:

```
unichr(int('e3', 16)).encode('cp1252')
```

Comment: Thank you! In Python3 all I needed was `a = chr(int('e3', 16))`.